# How to run an async function through the task scheduler (aioschedule)?

Tags: python, async-await, schedule, aiohttp, aiogram

I am writing a personal telegram bot, one of its functions is to show the balance of my accounts [market.csgo.com](https://market.csgo.com/). My code:

```
import asyncio
import aiogram
import aiohttp

...

async def get_balance(session, profiles_dict, message):
    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/get-money?key={profiles_dict[1][1]}') as resp:
        html = await resp.json()

        each_wallet = int(html['money'])

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
            f' <a href="{profiles_dict[1][0]}">{profiles_dict[0]}</a> : <i>{each_wallet}</i>',
            disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)

...

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message):
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        if message.text == 'Balance ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')

            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i, message, stats))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        if message.text == 'On Sale ':
            ...

        if message.text == 'Timeout Items ⌛':
            ...


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

`get_balance()` works in async mode, sends `aiohttp` requests to the API and outputs information `await bot.send_message()`. Result:

[image]

Now the launch of the function is implemented through the keyboard button, but how to make the function run every hour? I am aware of the existence of asynchronous task scheduler [aioschedule](https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/) and have seen [this example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144849/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-aiogram-%D0%B8-schedule-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A2elegram-bot). But they run a function without arguments, but I have as many as 3 of them `async def get_balance(session, profiles_dict, message)`. I tried to do this:

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule

async def scheduler(session, profiles_dict, message):
    aioschedule.every().hour.do(get_balance(session, profiles_dict, message))
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(session, profiles_dict, message):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler(session, profiles_dict, message))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup(session, profiles_dict, message))
```

Obviously it doesn't work that way.
[image]

My question is:

**How to run an async function with arguments that sends `aiohttp` requests through task scheduling `aioschedule` and display the result through telegram `aiogram`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import aiogram
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aioschedule

...

async def get_balance(session, profiles_dict):
    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/get-money?key={profiles_dict[1][1]}') as resp:
        html = await resp.json()

        each_wallet = int(html['money'])

        await bot.send_message(MY_TELEGRAM_ID,
            f' <a href="{profiles_dict[1][0]}">{profiles_dict[0]}</a> : <i>{each_wallet}</i>',
            disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)

...

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message):
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        if message.text == 'Balance ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')

            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        if message.text == 'On Sale ':
            ...

        if message.text == 'Timeout Items ⌛':
            ...


# Client session get_balance function
async def session_get_balance():
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        for i in profiles.items():
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


# Schedule functions by time
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().hour.do(session_get_balance)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


# Function at start
async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


# Launch telegram bot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Since this is my personal bot, instead of `message.from_user.id` I specified my `MY_TELEGRAM_ID`.

```
await bot.send_message(MY_TELEGRAM_ID,
            f' <a href="{profiles_dict[1][0]}">{profiles_dict[0]}</a> : <i>{each_wallet}</i>',
            disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
```